# JavaFX how to handle titledpane expandproperty?

Tags: javafx

I'm testing an application which can write texts to a `TextArea` as soon as I open a `TitlePane`. I coded my app so that when I click the title of titlepane2, some text should be written in the `textArea2` and it's working fine.

But the problem is: **how can some text be written when I click the finish button located in titlepane1?**

As you can see, if the `finish` button clicked, `titlepane2` is going to be expanded and some text should be written in textArea2.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;

public class TitlePaneTestController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TitledPane titlePane1;
    @FXML private TitledPane titlePane2;
    @FXML private TextArea textArea1;
    @FXML private TextArea textArea2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleTitlePane1Clicked() {
        textArea1.appendText("This is TitlePane 1");
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleTitle1Finished() {
        titlePane1.setExpanded(false);
        titlePane2.setExpanded(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleTitlePane2Clicked() {
        textArea2.appendText("This is TitlePane 2");
    }

}
```

this is the FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="smallframework.TitlePaneTestController">
   <children>
      <Accordion layoutX="107.0" layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane fx:id="titlePane1" animated="false" text="Step 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <VBox prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextArea fx:id="textArea1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleTitle1Finished" text="Finish" />
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane fx:id="titlePane2" animated="false" text="Step 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <VBox prefHeight="353.0" prefWidth="598.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextArea fx:id="textArea2" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                              <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Finish" />
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register a listener with the `expandedProperty` of each titled pane:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    titlePane1.expandedProperty().addListener((obs, wasExpanded, isNowExpanded) -> {
        if (isNowExpanded) {
            textArea1.appendText("Titled Pane 1 selected");
        }
    }
    titlePane2.expandedProperty().addListener((obs, wasExpanded, isNowExpanded) -> {
        if (isNowExpanded) {
            textArea2.appendText("Titled Pane 2 selected");
        }
    }
}
```